# need help to expand logic funtion

Tags: python-3.x

I need help to create a function to do as following:
* if the input string is "-00-" Then output of function will be a list of ["0000","1000","0001","1001"].

*if the input string is "1--1-0" then the output is ["100100","110100","101100",....,"111110"]

*if the input string is "111111", e.g without any "-", return "111111"

```
def seperate (sub_array):
    return_array=[]
    b= [x for x in sub_array]
    #print (b)
    empty_array =[]

    def dash (lis):
        global count
        count = 0
        empty_array1 = lis.copy()
        empty_array2 = lis.copy()


        for n,i in enumerate(lis):
            if (i == "-"):
                empty_array1[n]= "0"
                empty_array2[n]= "1"
                empty_array.append(empty_array1)
                empty_array.append(empty_array2)

                return empty_array1 , empty_array2
            else:
                return lis

    emp1, emp2 =(dash(b))

    return_array.append((dash(emp1)))
    return_array.append((dash(emp2)))

    return return_array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). You can read the docs for detailed explanation.

```
from itertools import product
def seperate (sub_array):
    ct = sub_array.count('-')
    # repeat 0 or 1 for ct number of times
    cartesian = product(range(2), repeat=ct) 
    fm = sub_array.replace('-', '{}')
    # unpack each cartesian product to fill in '{}'
    return [fm.format(*c) for c in cartesian] 

print(seperate('-11-1-'))
```